# jQuery-Tokeninput not displaying results from JSON results

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-tokeninput

**View**

```
= text_field_tag :food_tokens
```

**FoodsController**

```
def search
  @foods = Food.where("name LIKE ?" , "%#{params[:q]}%")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @foods.as_json(only: [:id, :name]) }
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
match '/search' => 'foods#search'
```

**application.js**

```
$(function() {
  $('#food_tokens').tokenInput('/search.json', { crossDomain: false }
});
```

**Output from /search.json**

```
[{"id":"5","name":"Apple"},{"id":"6","name":"Burger"}]
```

When I start typing 'Apple' into the text field, I get the "No results" message.

Any insights?

Comment: what does `$.get('/search.json');` returns?

Comment: `$.get('/search.json`); returns this object.
`Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

I left out a lot of of its content, but within it is this:
`responseText: "[{"id":"5","name":"Apple"},{"id":"6","name":"Burger"}]"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that you didn't closed the `.tokenInput` method properly, should be like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#food_tokens').tokenInput('/search.json', { crossDomain: false });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to close `.tokenInput` in the OP. Out of frustration, I switched to using https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js and have achieved success. I'll still keep the this tokeninput issue branch in case someone figures out what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the capital letter. I had a similar problem and I changed the code slightly. First, I changed `"name LIKE ?"` for `"name ILIKE ?"` following this SO question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12453008/1799880). Secondly, I changed the line 797 of `jquery.tokeninput.js` from this

```
if(input_box.val().toLowerCase() === query) {
   populate_dropdown(query, settings.jsonContainer ? results[settings.jsonContainer] : results);
}
```

to this

```
if(input_box.val() === query) {
  populate_dropdown(query, settings.jsonContainer ? results[settings.jsonContainer] : results);
}
```